# GetOwinContext Entity Framework not retrieving navigation property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 6.x in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with Identity 2.0. I added supplemental profile information which is stored in a separate table than AspNetUsers. For that, my ApplicationUser class has a property like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    public virtual SupplementalProfile Supplemental { get; set; }
        :
}
```

And the supplemental profile looks like this

```
public class SuplementalProfile {
    [Key] public string Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50), MaxLength(50), Required] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50), MaxLength(50), Required] public string LastName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryCode")] public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller code I am trying to use some of the properties of the supplemental profile like this:

```
ApplicationUser appuser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
MyDatabaseContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
Currency currency = MyDatabaseContext.Currencies.Where(c => c.CountryCode == appuser.Supplemental.CountryCode).FirstOrDefault();
return currency
```

But I am getting an exception that said the target must be static. As I found out that seems to be thrown because the c.CountryCode value in the lambda expression is null. In fact, it turns out that while appuser does represent a valid user, when I try to access the Supplemental navigation property I get a null.

Why is it not fetching the supplemental profile from the navigation property?